# php artisan migrate: Class Schema not found

Tags: php, database, laravel, web-applications, artisan-migrate

When doing a migration, in the Windows console I execute the command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

When I run the command, it shows me the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Market\Providers\Schema' not found
```

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 30):

add following line on the top of that page (AppServiceProvider.php under providers directory)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

or

```
use Schema;
```

Comment: To be more precise the `AppServiceProvider.php` file is located in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` just to clarify and make it easy for people

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you have fixed another problems with the message "Laravel 5.4: Specified key was too long error" using [this article](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error) where you were recommended to add following code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

to the file named

> AppServiceProvider.php

and you actually only changed the `boot` method and forget to update the `use` section. Am I right?

The Article says:

> Laravel 5.4 made a change to the default database character set, and
>   it’s now utf8mb4 which includes support for storing emojis. This only
>   affects new applications and as long as you are running MySQL v5.7.7
>   and higher you do not need to do anything.
>
> For those running MariaDB or older versions of MySQL you may hit this
>   error when trying to run migrations:
>
> ```
> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is
> 767 bytes (SQL: alter table users add unique
> users_email_unique(email))
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071
> Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
> ```

Answer (score 4):

It seems your migration code is in a namespace and that's where PHP is looking for **Schema** class. Add the following at the top of your file:

```
use Schema;
```

or refer to the **Schema** class using fully qualified namespace:

```
\Schema::table(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding to your AppServiceProvider.php file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
 {
   Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
 }
```

Don't forget to run

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

I kept facing the same issue because i hadn't migrated fresh (ie drop tables and create new ones)